# Splitting a string and extracting decimal place information and min and max values using strsplit

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr, strsplit

I have some data which looks like:

```
     grp  grp2                                            figures
1  10016 13567                                        0.55 - 0.65
2   1270  2090                                           1.90 - 2
3   8757 12259                              6.60 - 7\n8.50 - 9.50
4   2589  3982                                        2.75 - 3.15
5   9099 12573 1.24 - 1.30\n1.22 - 1.30\n0.08 - 0.10\n0.10 - 0.12
6   5211  8334                                        6.90 - 7.40
7   9994 13542                                        2.73 - 2.78
8   2685  4113              0.72 - 0.74\n2.75 - 2.77\n3.10 - 3.18
9   9778 13295            32 - 39\n190 - 200\n142 - 152\n90 - 100
10   772  1317                                        2.20 - 2.40
```

I would like to extract some information from the `figures` column. I want to split the columns up into `min` and `max` which can be done by splitting `-` using something like `strsplit(dat$figures, split = "-")` (but I want it into two columns `min` and `max`). Once I have this, I would like to add a new column which gives me a `0` or `1` whether the observation contains a decimal or not. I would like to do this line by line, some observations contain `\n`, so my expected output for the following observation `1.24 - 1.30\n1.22 - 1.30\n0.08 - 0.10\n0.10 - 0.12` would be.

```
min     max      containsDecimal
1.24    1.30           1
1.22    1.30           1
0.08    0.10           1
0.10    0.12           1
```

The following `32 - 39\n190 - 200\n142 - 152\n90 - 100` example would look like:

```
min    max       containsDecimal
32     39             0
190    200            0
142    152            0
90     100            0
```

Where, now the column `containsDecimal` is `0`. I am trying to get the results to be contained inside of the cell where that observation is and split by `\n` and not expanded out.

Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(grp = c("10016", "1270", "8757", "2589", "9099", 
"5211", "9994", "2685", "9778", "772"), grp2 = c(13567L, 2090L, 
12259L, 3982L, 12573L, 8334L, 13542L, 4113L, 13295L, 1317L), 
    figures = c("0.55 - 0.65", "1.90 - 2", "6.60 - 7\n8.50 - 9.50", 
    "2.75 - 3.15", "1.24 - 1.30\n1.22 - 1.30\n0.08 - 0.10\n0.10 - 0.12", 
    "6.90 - 7.40", "2.73 - 2.78", "0.72 - 0.74\n2.75 - 2.77\n3.10 - 3.18", 
    "32 - 39\n190 - 200\n142 - 152\n90 - 100", "2.20 - 2.40")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible tidyverse solution would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(figures = str_split(figures, "\n")) %>% 
  unnest_longer(figures) %>% 
  separate(figures, into = c("min", "max"), " - ", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(contains_decimal = if_else(grepl(".", min, fixed = TRUE) | grepl(".", max, fixed = TRUE), 1, 0))

# A tibble: 19 x 5
   grp    grp2    min    max contains_decimal
   <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 10016 13567   0.55   0.65                1
 2 1270   2090   1.9    2                   1
 3 8757  12259   6.6    7                   1
 4 8757  12259   8.5    9.5                 1
 5 2589   3982   2.75   3.15                1
 6 9099  12573   1.24   1.3                 1
 7 9099  12573   1.22   1.3                 1
 8 9099  12573   0.08   0.1                 1
 9 9099  12573   0.1    0.12                1
10 5211   8334   6.9    7.4                 1
11 9994  13542   2.73   2.78                1
12 2685   4113   0.72   0.74                1
13 2685   4113   2.75   2.77                1
14 2685   4113   3.1    3.18                1
15 9778  13295  32     39                   0
16 9778  13295 190    200                   0
17 9778  13295 142    152                   0
18 9778  13295  90    100                   0
19 772    1317   2.2    2.4                 1
```

Comment: I think this almost gets what I want but this doubles the dataset in size almost, is there a way to keep the dataset the same size and keep the format - i.e. separated by `\n`.

Comment: So do you want to obtain several min/max columns, one for each pair of numbers separated by `\n`? What would be the expected output for a row like `32 - 39\n190 - 200\n142 - 152\n90 - 100`?

Comment: Yes, as the data is currently in the `figures` column (where each observation/row is separated by a `\n` - new line - I would like the output the same as that (each result separated by a new line `\n`.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear to me yet. It would be better if you edit your question with the expected output of the sample dataset `dat` (please be specific)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- mutate(dat, figs = stringr::str_split(figures, "\n")) # produces a list column. In the other words, some of the rows of `figs`  column have more than one element. 
dat <- unnest(dat, col = figs)
dat <- separate(dat, figs,c("min", "max"), "-") # you could use convert = TRUE, to convert min and max into numeric. 
dat <- mutate(dat, contains_decimal = grepl("\\.", min) & grepl("\\.", max)) # since type of min and max are characters, containing decimal mean containing literally a period.
```

```
# A tibble: 19 x 6
   grp    grp2 figures                            min    max    contains_decimal
   <chr> <int> <chr>                              <chr>  <chr>  <lgl>           
 1 10016 13567 "0.55 - 0.65"                      "0.55… " 0.6… TRUE            
 2 1270   2090 "1.90 - 2"                         "1.90… " 2"   FALSE           
 3 8757  12259 "6.60 - 7\n8.50 - 9.50"            "6.60… " 7"   FALSE           
 4 8757  12259 "6.60 - 7\n8.50 - 9.50"            "8.50… " 9.5… TRUE            
 5 2589   3982 "2.75 - 3.15"                      "2.75… " 3.1… TRUE            
 6 9099  12573 "1.24 - 1.30\n1.22 - 1.30\n0.08 -… "1.24… " 1.3… TRUE            
 7 9099  12573 "1.24 - 1.30\n1.22 - 1.30\n0.08 -… "1.22… " 1.3… TRUE            
 8 9099  12573 "1.24 - 1.30\n1.22 - 1.30\n0.08 -… "0.08… " 0.1… TRUE            
 9 9099  12573 "1.24 - 1.30\n1.22 - 1.30\n0.08 -… "0.10… " 0.1… TRUE            
10 5211   8334 "6.90 - 7.40"                      "6.90… " 7.4… TRUE            
11 9994  13542 "2.73 - 2.78"                      "2.73… " 2.7… TRUE            
12 2685   4113 "0.72 - 0.74\n2.75 - 2.77\n3.10 -… "0.72… " 0.7… TRUE            
13 2685   4113 "0.72 - 0.74\n2.75 - 2.77\n3.10 -… "2.75… " 2.7… TRUE            
14 2685   4113 "0.72 - 0.74\n2.75 - 2.77\n3.10 -… "3.10… " 3.1… TRUE            
15 9778  13295 "32 - 39\n190 - 200\n142 - 152\n9… "32 "  " 39"  FALSE           
16 9778  13295 "32 - 39\n190 - 200\n142 - 152\n9… "190 " " 200" FALSE           
17 9778  13295 "32 - 39\n190 - 200\n142 - 152\n9… "142 " " 152" FALSE           
18 9778  13295 "32 - 39\n190 - 200\n142 - 152\n9… "90 "  " 100" FALSE           
19 772    1317 "2.20 - 2.40"                      "2.20… " 2.4… TRUE
```